# Split a JSP table list by system date using "<c" with If and Else

Tags: html, jsp, if-statement, html-table

I want to display a list of trips a "user" is attending.
i want it split into "coming up" and "previous" tables. 
At the moment it just displays all trips in the arraylist.

I want to create an If Else loop that would say "if date is later add column to this table"
else " add column to this table"

INFO:

- Creating two tables is an option
- i can feed all date's from the arraylist
- date format is "dd-mm-yyyy"

SUMMERY QUESTION : How do i get the system date and then split data according to before/after that date

```
<jsp:useBean id="userTripList" type="java.util.ArrayList" scope="session" />
    <table border ="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Trip Name:</td>
            <td>Initiator:</td>
            <td>Initiator Photo:</td>
            <td>Initiator Car Photo:</td>
            <td>Number Of Passengers:</td>
            <td>Cost Of Trip Per Passenger:</td>
            <td>Festival:</td>
            <td>Arrival Date:</td>
            <td>Departure Date:</td>
            <td>Trip Passengers:</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${userTripList}" var="trip">
            <tr>
                <td>${trip.tripName}</td>
                <td>${trip.initiator}</td>
                <td>${trip}</td>
                <td>${trip}</td>
                <td>${trip.numberOfPassengers}</td>
                <td>${trip.costOfTripPerPassenger}</td>
                <td>${trip.festival}</td>
                <td>${trip.arrivalDate}</td>
                <td>${trip.departureDate}</td>
                <td>${trip}</td> 
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job that should be done by the controller, in Java code, and not by the view. Make it split the list in two, store both lists in two request attributes, and have your JSP simply have two separate loops, without any date comparison needed.